# Updating the header on every page from one file

Tags: html, include-path

Dreamweaver library elements are buggy and cause so many updating problems and I don't want to use them anymore. How does everyone else update, for example, the header section of every html page simultaneously without having to manually edit each page?

Comment: I considered https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp but wonder whether theres a way without JS

Comment: Have you tried looking at software like a site generator? Jekyll uses liquid, which has an include statement https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/

Comment: I thought there'd be a simpler way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's 3 ways that aren't javascript's include function:

You could have php on your stack, and include files with php:

```
<?php
include('header.html');
```

This way used to be standard a long time ago, but no new site should be doing this anymore.

You could use a site generator, like Jekyll. Jekyll parses liquid statements on generation:

```
{% include header.html %}
```

This staticcms type of site generation is modern

You could use a javascript framework, like Angular. With angular, your pages get placed inside of a container div, and then you can put anything that shows up on every page (header, nav, footer) outside of the container:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- SCROLLS -->
  <!-- load bootstrap and fontawesome via CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />

  <!-- SPELLS -->
  <!-- load angular and angular route via CDN -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- HEADER AND NAVBAR -->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Angular Routing Example</a>
            </div>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about"><i class="fa fa-shield"></i> About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
    <div id="main">

        <!-- angular templating -->
        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

Personally, I use angular. At work, our sites are react apps built in Jekyll. I assume that Facebook uses php, or a php framework like CodeIgniter

Comment: is that what people really do just to include a couple of files? I'm quite surprised there is no simpler solution. I'd rather not have to include external libraries like Angular etc as these affect page speeds

Comment: Of course it's not the only way, like you said there are ways using javascript to fill divs with html. But, your question asked how other people do it, and these are the most common ways I've seen webdevs build includes in the industry